# How to get BIC/AIC plot for selecting number of Principal Components in Python or R

Tags: python, r, pca

I want to get a plot like this one for selecting number of components in a PCA:[image]

I am however stuck trying to manually code the BIC/AIC. Are there any packages in either R or Python that can help me get this? Any sample code would greatly help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [a link](http://pages.pomona.edu/~jsh04747/courses/math158/multlin4.pdf) to some example R code that computes AIC and BIC, as well as forward/backward/stepwise variable selection. All credit goes to Jo Hardin. I will reproduce part of the code below for convenience, slightly edited for formatting:

```
> sat.data <- read.table("sat.csv", header=T, sep=",")
> attach(sat.data)
> sat.n <- nrow(sat.data) # be careful with missing values!!
> ltakers <- log(takers) # variable is quite right skewed
```

AIC and BIC in R

Method 1:

```
> sat.lm0 <- lm(sat ~ 1)
> summary(sat.lm0)

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 948.45 10.21 92.86 <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1 1

Residual standard error: 71.5 on 48 degrees of freedom

> sat.sse0 <- sum(resid(sat.lm0) ^2)
> sat.n + sat.n*log(2*pi) + sat.n * log(sat.sse0 / sat.n) + 2 * (1+1)
[1] 560.4736
> AIC(sat.lm0, k=2)
[1] 560.4736
> sat.n + sat.n * log(2*pi) + sat.n*log(sat.sse0/sat.n) + log(sat.n)*(1+1)
[1] 564.2573
> AIC(sat.lm0, k=log(sat.n))
[1] 564.2573
```

Method 2:

```
> sat.lm1 <- lm(sat ~ ltakers)
> summary(sat.lm1)

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 1112.408 12.386 89.81 <2e-16 ***
ltakers -59.175 4.167 -14.20 <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes: 0 *** 0.001 ** 0.01 * 0.05 . 0.1 1

Residual standard error: 31.41 on 47 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.811, Adjusted R-squared: 0.807
F-statistic: 201.7 on 1 and 47 DF, p-value: < 2.2e-16

> sat.sse1 <- sum(resid(sat.lm1) ^2)
> sat.n + sat.n*log(2*pi) + sat.n * log(sat.sse1 / sat.n) + 2 * (2+1)
[1] 480.832
> AIC(sat.lm1, k=2)
[1] 480.832
> sat.n + sat.n * log(2*pi) + sat.n*log(sat.sse1/sat.n) + log(sat.n) * (2+1)
[1] 486.5075
> AIC(sat.lm1, k=log(sat.n))
[1] 486.5075
```